# What is a recommended approach on Power BI designer files management

Tags: powerbi

We are a team of several people. We all build queries and generate reports which we later publish to app.powerbi.com.
We are looking for the best approach to collaborate with each other. There could be some shared queries, we need to see and modify each others reports and data.
What is the recommended approach? Should there be just one common pbix file or multiple? Should there be some common shared folder in the network?

Answer (score 0):

Using a network share (a shared folder, SharePoint, OneDrive, Dropbox) is advised. The biggest issue is with query sources that look at the file system. Recommend you factor your queries so they have a single Source query that you can modify if it's machine specific, then use the 'reference' feature in the query view to reference that for any derivative queries. For common data, you can use a shared onedrive folder (if you're using files).  When you upload your reports to PowerBI.com, create a group and ensure your team members are in the group.  HTH.

Answer (score 0):

pbix files are not really designed for shared development so use some sort of version control system.   This will allow you to save your changes regularly so that if someone else picks up the file to work on it will be up to date.   The VC allows you to easily roll back if need be so you don't have to be shy about committing changes.   Inevitably you will end up treading on each others toes at some point but VC will help in sorting things out.

Dropbox is a good shared folder for teams and easy to setup.   For a free alternative you could use gitHub although that is a little more difficult to use.

Personally, as a Visual Studio user I save my Power BI files under a solution folder so that it is in the same place as related database scripts, app code etc.   Visual Studio detects any changes made to the file and then version controls via Team Services.